# Two periods of a periodic element in a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid, $x \in M$ and assume  $$x^k = x^{k+d}$$ holds for some $k \geq 0$ and $d>0$. Assume that also $$x^{k'} = x^{k' + d'}$$ holds for some $k' \geq 0$ and $d'>0$. Does this imply that $$x^{\min(k,k')} = x^{\min(k,k') + \mathrm{gcd}(d,d')}?$$

Equivalently: Let $\sim$ be a congruence on the monoid $(\mathbb{N},+)$ with $k \sim k+d$ and $k' \sim k' + d'$. Does this imply $\min(k,k') \sim \min(k,k') + \mathrm{gcd}(d,d')$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong but in any finite cyclic monoid $\langle x \rangle = C_{n,m}$ your statement is always true. It follows that if $x^k = x^{k+d}$ then $k\geq n$ and we have $x^k = x^{k+d} \Leftrightarrow d = 0\pmod m$.

Comment: Your equivalence only holds when $k \geq n$.

Comment: That is true indeed, I'll edit it

Comment: I'm doubtful about your assumption that $M = \langle x \rangle$. If it is true, then it's much easier: it is a [Monogenic semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_semigroup), but is it necessarily so?

Comment: Of course we may assume $M=\langle x \rangle$ since everything takes place only there. btw: monogenic is just a fancy word for cyclic.

Comment: @HeinrichD In that case, every element of the form $x^n$, with $n \geq k$ sits inside the cyclic group which is a subsemigroup of this monoid. So $x^{\min(k,k')}$ is there too, by your two equalities, and then, inside the group, $y^d = y^{d'} =1$. Then if $h=\gcd(d,d')$, there are integers $u,v$ with $h=du+d'v$ and $y^h = y^{du+d'v} = y^{du}y^{d'v}=1$, and you're done, right?

Comment: @amrsa: Before reading it: This seems to be an answer, not just a comment to JJR. After reading it: What is $y$? Also I don't think that there is a cyclic group in our monoid. I mean, which generator?

Comment: @JJR: To complete your answer: $x^k=x^{k+d}$ actually implies $k \geq n$.

Comment: @HeinrichD Alright shall edit it Thx!